# How to convert a column timezone from CET to CST in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I am trying to convert date column value from `CET` to `CST`.
I tried using `NEW_TIME(SYSDATE ,'CET','CST')` function, but it's giving an error saying unknown time zone. Issue here is `CET` is not recognised by oracle as valid timezone.

I tried using "at timezone" approach initially, but it's inserting the timezone name in the column value, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three-character timezones don't adjust for daylight savings. To do that you need to use the fully specified timezone name. To illustrate, in Canada, there is central standard time, but the province of Saskatechewan does not use daylight savings, so if I want to convert right now to local time in summer where daylight savings is in play, and knowing the correct fully specified timezone names in the DB Timezone file (You can check the list installed in your DB by select * from V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;):

```
SELECT 'Central' locale
      , extract(timezone_abbr from cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Canada/Central') tz_abbrv
      , CAST(cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Canada/Central' as timestamp) local_time from dual
union all
SELECT 'Saskatchewan' locale
      , extract(timezone_abbr from cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Canada/Saskatchewan') tz_abbrv
     , CAST(cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Canada/Saskatchewan' as timestamp) local_time from dual;

LOCALE       TZ_ABBRV   LOCAL_TIME                          
Central      CDT        03/08/2016 9:57:24.000000 AM        
Saskatchewan CST        03/08/2016 8:57:24.000000 AM
```

Otherwise you would need to code when to switch between CST and DST in your calculations - bearing in mind that the rules for when daylight savings starts and ends has changed over time, and may change again in the future.

So respond to your comment about inserts, you need to first ensure that the column is defined to include the time zone (datatype "timestamp with timezone"), and change the CAST from "timestamp" to "timestamp with time zone" to make sure that the zone information is stored:

e.g.)

```
create table mbt (stz timestamp with time zone)

insert into mbt values (CAST(cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Indian/Maldives' as timestamp with time zone) )

insert into mbt values (CAST(cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Canada/Eastern' as timestamp with time zone) )

commit;

select * from mbt;

STZ                                        
05/08/2016 8:06:49.000000 PM +05:00        
05/08/2016 11:06:50.000000 AM -04:00
```

If you don't include the WITH TIME ZONE you should still get the changed value, but you won't be able to easily translate from local time to a different timezone as the values will be assumed to be in the server timezone:

```
drop table mbt;

create table mbt (stz timestamp);

insert into mbt values (CAST(cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Indian/Maldives' as timestamp) );

insert into mbt values (CAST(cast(add_months(sysdate,6) as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'Canada/Eastern' as timestamp ) );

commit;

select * from mbt;


STZ                            
-------------------------------
05-AUG-16 08.13.16.000000 PM   
05-AUG-16 11.13.16.000000 AM
```

Comment: @ MichaelBroughton :Above Timezone conversion method is working for SELECT queries, But when I used it in INSERT query it's inserting plain SYSDATE value instead of converted value.

Comment: Updated the answer to help you out with this

Answer (score 0):

To remove timezone you can use `cast(.... as Timesamp)`. 
Check my example.

`select cast( current_timestamp at time zone 'CST' as timestamp), cast( current_timestamp at time zone 'CST' as timestamp with time zone) from dual;`

Comment: Worked like a gem, But I have seen in its documentation, that it will not adjust for the day light savings time, Is there anyway we can adjust that in the same function.

Comment: added an answer below to show how to deal with Daylight Savings. It requires you know more than the abbreviated timezone for your locales.

Comment: Above Timezone conversion method is working for SELECT queries, But when I used it in INSERT query it's inserting plain SYSDATE value instead of converted value.